# Touch screen driver for windows 7 , multiple monitor

Tags: c++, windows, mapping, touch, driver

I am developing a touch screen driver for windows 7 , it works fine when a single display is attached but when i attach a secondary display the touch inputs get mapped only to the primary display . 
Is there any way in which i can map the touch inputs to the secondary monitor ?

Any inputs or pointers will be greatly appreciated ?.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible in Windows 7, but according to MSDN should be possible in Windows 8:

> **HID Descriptor for Digitizers**
>
> Starting with Windows 8, a touch digitizer must appear as a touch screen (page = 0x0D, usage = 0x04). A stylus digitizer must appear as an integrated pen (page = 0x0D, usage = 0x02) or an external pen (page = 0x0D, usage = 0x01). **Integrated touch and pen devices are mapped to the display that they are physically connected to**. External pen devices are mapped to the virtual desktop.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj151564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a tablet pc service, then it is possible to map the display using the `Wisp` registry keys under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Wisp`.

However, if you are relying completely on HID touch of the device, then you will need to use Windows' touch calibration settings to map the display appropriately.